# MongoDb: $elemMatch with convert string to number

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I use MongoDB and I have such a collection. First I select all documents with *tableId = 1*, then I group them by *itemId* - I get 2 groups of 2 documents. And in conclusion, I need to leave such groups where there are such documents: 1) city = London, 2) year is greater than or equal to some value. And to do this, I need to convert the value from a string to a number. How can this be done?

In my query below, the part where the year is compared is an error.

```
    [
      {
        "tableId": 1,
        "itemId": 10,
        "name": "City",
        "value": "London"
      },
      {
        "tableId": 1,
        "itemId": 10,
        "name": "StartYear",
        "value": "2017"
      },
      {
        "tableId": 1,
        "itemId": 20,
        "name": "City",
        "value": "Paris"
      },
      {
        "tableId": 1,
        "itemId": 20,
        "name": "StartYear",
        "value": "2018"
      },
      {
        "tableId": 2,
        "itemId": 30,
        "name": "City",
        "value": "Madrid"
      },
      {
        "tableId": 2,
        "itemId": 30,
        "name": "StartYear",
        "value": "2016"
      }
    ]
```

My query is:

```js
    db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        "$match": {
          tableId: 1
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          _id: {
            itemId: "$itemId"
          },
          result: {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          $and: [
            {
              "result": {
                $elemMatch: {
                  "name": "City",
                  "value": "London"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "result": {
                $elemMatch: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      "name": "StartYear"
                    },
                    {
                      $lte: [
                        {
                          $toDouble: "$value"
                        },
                        2018
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a conditional mapping first to convert the year to a numeric value using `$map` first. Then perform your `$elemMatch` criteria.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      tableId: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "value": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              "$name",
              "StartYear"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            $toInt: "$value"
          },
          "else": "$value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: {
        itemId: "$itemId"
      },
      result: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $and: [
        {
          "result": {
            $elemMatch: {
              "name": "City",
              "value": "London"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "result": {
            $elemMatch: {
              "name": "StartYear",
              "value": {
                $lte: 2018
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r1QITQ8CZFe) for your reference.

Comment: Works great for this collection. But my real data is more complicated: many different fields, hierarchy. How will the map work?

Comment: @egeo updated the solution to put the conditional conversion in earlier stage to avoid constructing large `$map` content

Comment: A good change. A small drawback: in the database, value is stored as a string, and returned as a number. This is fine for me, but another might like to see the original data types.

Comment: @egeo Please see [this version](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9BdWbtAc3N8) that used an auxiliary field for conversion. However, I suggest storing the value in proper datatype if possible to avoid this sort of conversion overhead in the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Query

- group and count if `name/value` is found and if `startYear/value` is found
- keep those that both are found
- unset the 2 temp fields `cityFound,yearFound`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70450726-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$tableId", 1]}}},
 {"$group":
  {"_id":"$itemId",
   "cityFound":
   {"$sum":
    {"$cond":
     [{"$and":
       [{"$eq":["$name", "City"]}, {"$eq":["$value", "London"]}]},
      1, 0]}},
   "yearFound":
   {"$sum":
    {"$cond":
     [{"$and":
       [{"$eq":["$name", "StartYear"]},
        {"$lte":[{"$toInt":"$value"}, 2018]}]},
      1, 0]}},
   "result":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$match":
  {"$expr":
   {"$and":[{"$gt":["$cityFound", 0]}, {"$gt":["$yearFound", 0]}]}}},
 {"$unset":["cityFound", "yearFound"]}])
```

The above is fast because it does the check while grouping.

To convert a string to number we can do `$toInt` or `toDouble`.
But those are aggregate operators, and in match they should be under `$expr`.

The problem with your query is that you are using aggregate expressions inside a query operator, this doesn't work, for example `$value` is aggregate expression, also `$toDouble` you cant use both.

Instead of elem-match, you could use `$filter` that allows aggregation expressions inside, and check if after filter array would be empty.